# Problem accessing static variables from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I've got a class

```
class KeyConstants:
   VK_CTLR = 37
   VK_SHIFT = 50
   VK_ALT = 65
```

and some code using the class

```
class EventListener(threading.Thread)
    ... snip ...
    def is_modkey(self, event):
         return event.detail == KeyConstants.VK_CTRL
```

And then I get **AttributeError, KeyConstants does not have attribute VK_CTLR** , why can't I access the static variables from another thread?

Comment: The thread shouldn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: I noticed that the attribute is defined as `VK_CTLR` but used as `VK_CTRL` (with R and L swapped)... is it so also in your original code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the attribute is defined as `VK_CTLR` but used as `VK_CTRL` (with R and L swapped)... Maybe it is just a typing error...

Answer (score 1):

If you can access KeyConstants, you should be able to access it's attributes. The error is likely somewhere else.